# Проблема ajax.

Tags: ajax, php

Как к посту ajax присвоить ключик, который будет генерироваться каждый раз через клик по картинке (тексту), что бы можно было на сервере проверять, равен ли полученный ключ реальному.

Тем самым нельзя будет засунуть запрос в прогу и накрутить.

Каким способом можно это реализовать ?

Comment: > Тем самым нельзя будет засунуть запрос в прогу и накрутить.
> 

Можно.


Comment: Можно, но как ?

Comment: Двумя запросами. Первый - получает хеш, второй использует его.

Comment: Можно подробнее ?
Как это выглядит в самом коде.
Буквально две строки =)

Comment: Вы всё равно не поймете как его применить ...

Comment: shurik с чего ты взял что я такой непонятливый ?
Ты напиши, а с кодом я разберусь сам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гуглите "метод трех рукопожатий". Клиенту приходит хэш ключа, на клиенте ключом хэшируются данные, при отправке на сервере проверяется.

hk - хэш ключа, hv - хэш значения, key - ключ, value - значение, varr - массив допустимых значений

```
1. php: сбросить ключ, записать в сессию новый(хэш рандома), отправить hk=md5(key)
2. js: отправить hv=md5(hk+value)
3. php: 
if (@$sent = $_GET['hv']) {
  $newval = false;
  foreach ($varr as $val)
    if (md5(md5($_SESSION['key']).$val) == $sent) {
      $newval = $val;
      break;
    }
  if (!$newval) { $_SESSION['key'] = md5(rand(40000, 900000)); die('hack'); }
  // здесь у нас значение $newval, которе без входа на страницу получить очень сложно
  // алсо, если вам это интересно, практически невозможно угнать данные между клиентом и сервером
}
```

Дополнительно можно ключ посылать клиенту в замусоренном виде, в случайном месте куска кода 1-2кб + собирать его из нескольких частей. + можно отсылать несколько ключей(key1..key16), а в сессию записывать верный номер ключа.

Тогда это можно автоматизировать только AutoIt'ом) НО от этого можно картинку выводить в случайном месте на странице со случайным id переменной длины. Тогда способов поломать - нет =) Только китайца кликать посадить, но это дорого)

**UPD**

Ах да, еще можно сам алгоритм хэширования записывать в сессию :)

```
// сброс ключа
$alg = array(
  0 => '$result = md5(md5(rand(0, 10000)));',
  1 => '$result = sha1(md5(\'lol\').rand(90, 100).sha1($_SERVER[\'USER_AGENT\']));'
);
eval(array_rand($alg, 1));
$_SESSION['key'] = $result;
```

И таки да, стоит уточнить - это есть paranoid security: сложность взлома кошмарная, но нагрузка на сервер тоже неплохая.

Comment: Но от накруток это нисколько не спасет.

Comment: Ээ почему? это как минимум 3 запроса(получить html, получить js, отправить) + необходимо исполнять js на клиенте. Один запрос дважды не пройдет, ключ сбрасывается. Софтина хорошая нужна специально для этой страницы.

Comment: > Ээ почему?

Вы сами ответили:

> 3 запроса(получить html, получить js, отправить) + необходимо исполнять js на клиенте.

JS уже даже поисковые боты выполняют. Прикрутить v8 или воспользоваться чем-либо готовым вроде node.js не представляет никаких препятствий. 

Так что в качестве механизма от накруток я бы не рекомендовал подобное.

Comment: Ну, хм, после первого хакинг ахтунга вполне можно банить по IP. Опять же смотреть время между запросами (не менее 5 сек, например), смотреть кол-во запросов/время/ip. Я отвечал больше на первую часть вопроса, т.е. точно удостовериться, что данные от юзера пришли + сильно повысить сложность повторной отправки (не у всех кулхацкеров есть выделенка же).

Comment: Что значит после первого "ахтунга"? И прокси-сервера никто не отменял.

Да, от CSRF и подделки параметров такой метод более чем сойдет, но в качестве защиты от накруток я бы не стал на него полагаться. Имхо, распознавание боле-менее грамотной каптчи куда сложнее написать, чем притвориться полноценным браузером.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Выручил.